# How to detect if a placement would be empty (Doubleclick for Publishers)?

Tags: advertising, google-dfp

I want to use DFP for my ads. To display an ad I am calling `GA_googleFillSlot()`. My understanding of this is, that this function injects the ad code at the position where the JS call is placed. How can I detect if the placement is empty, e.g. no banner code will be injected because there is currently no banner. I need to know because the surrounding html needs to be adapted. Any ideas?

**Edit:**
Alternatively, is it possible to alter the injected html elements? DFP injects a div with id="google_ads_div_$PLACEMENT_ID">. Is it possible to add a class attribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using JavaScript, you can use the .innerHTML attribute to see if there is any HTML inside of the div after the GA_googleFillSlot().

And yes, the div tag supports both id and class attributes: [click](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_div.asp).

For coding questions similar to this, please direct them to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: It is not really a programming question, but a question about integration of a webservice.